# Can't scroll when using SpannedGridLayoutManager in Recyclerview in Android kotlin

Tags: android, kotlin, android-recyclerview, gridview

I am using the [spannedGridLayoutManager](https://github.com/noowenz/SpannedGridLayoutManager) library in android Kotlin for recyclerview, but I am having problems. When I filter the list of items obtained from the recyclerview API it cannot be scrolled. Meanwhile, when I don't filter the list from the recyclerview API, it can be scrolled.

This is me code after filtering data in API

Class Adapter:

```kotlin
override fun onBindViewHolder(holder: DynamicMenuViewHolder, position: Int) {
        with(holder){
            with(listDynamicMenu[position]){
                binding.descImg.text = this.titleEn
                binding.img.load(Constant.IMAGES_URL+this.image)

                binding.cardMenu.setOnClickListener { onMenuClick?.invoke(this) }
            }
        }
    }

    @SuppressLint("NotifyDataSetChanged")
    fun add(newMenu: List<SubmenuItem?>?){
        newMenu?.let {
            //val filteredMenu = it.filterNot { it?.link == "hotel_guide" } // List<SubmenuItem?>
            val filteredMenuNonNull = it.filterNotNull()
            listDynamicMenu.apply {
                clear()
                addAll(filteredMenuNonNull)
                notifyDataSetChanged()
            }
        }
    }
```

Detail code adapter and fragment:
[Adapter](https://pastebin.com/9xHvSryP)

Class Fragment:
[Fragment](https://pastebin.com/ScBXp1ir)